# Setting active text link based on mouse wheel scroll content + linking text links to each mouse wheel scroll content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this is a JS/ jQuery problem, and I have very decent CSS skills but sadly my JS knowledge is failing me big time. I bought a website template recently for my portfolio. It's a good one but I'm really struggling to adapt it.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- when you mouse wheel scroll (up or down) through each content block, the links below (at bottom of page) are active based on the content above. Forwards and backwards. So basically the text links at bottom would be bold depending on the active content above it.
- I'd also like the text links below to link to it's relevant content above. i.e. Project 3 would open Project 3 content (with the content animation).

For a start I've tried targeting each ID for the content blocks. i.e. id="project-3" then adding href="#project-3" but this is clearly not working. I also tried data-target="#project-3". Still no dice.

I'm trying to mimic the bottom navigation of this brilliant site here: http://fakemusic.fr/ (so as you wheel scroll through each artist, the links below are highlighted + they're clickable.

I made a Codepen here:

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/oioisaveloy/pen/eYzjGLr)
```

Apologies in advance, I couldn't work out how to de-activate the annoying preloader.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to highlight the project number which is current am i right ?

Comment: Still can't get this to work. If anyone can help, but they need more info or input from me. Let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery it is very easy

Give A unique data-id to your each "display-table" class and give a unique id also in anchor of "menu-item"

make a css class which has a highlight css like underline

then try jquery conditional js like if your "display-table class" has class "projects-item-active" then add class to anchor id and remove from siblings

and if someone clicking on anchor then add class "projects-item-active projects-item-animate" to "display-table" and remove from siblings.

click project 1 project 2 project 3 and see

Pen Added

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/mamun-rashid-raja/pen/zYBLRrp
```

Comment: Nice. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: i edited my ans and added pen first three links working (Y)

Comment: Looks really good, thanks. Only thing is, it breaks the mouse wheel scroll. i.e. when using the mouse wheel the content gets stuck on the 'active' content. So it doesn't scroll to previous project or next. Also, I'd really like the bottom links to change/ highlight as you scroll the mousewheel through the content? If that makes any sense?

Comment: because when scroll function is on "projects-item-animate" replaced with "projects-count-hide" you have to apply this also to class "projects-item-active"

Comment: i have updated the pen hope this help 

https://codepen.io/mamun-rashid-raja/pen/zYBLRrp

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like the mouse wheel is still not working. Also, the active link isn't highlighted. Another thing I didn't consider is the image for each content isn't changing. So it seems, when I click the bottom links it's just changing the content number and project name. Looks like it's much more complex than I thought. I'll try and delve in. Hopefully won't break it more :)

Comment: you have to connect each content with link via content id or class its easy
but its need time so i gives you just a idea how to do that... simple

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'll give that a try tomorrow.